unable to swap tokens on arbitrum sepolia using uniswap
I'm attempting to perform a token swap (WETH to MOR) on the Arbitrum Sepolia testnet using the Uniswap V3 API. The swap process consistently fails with the following error message:
missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] 

This error happens when I try different fee tiers (0.05%, 0.3%, and 1%), and the transaction reverts without a clear explanation. Below is the relevant portion of the error output:
Performing swap with account: 0x1237bbABAb2b9aC09a7dBC44A3e295D5fe2a318D
WETH balance before swap: 0.0167
MOR balance before swap: 15.749987
Attempting swap with 0.05% fee...
Quote failed for 0.05% fee: missing revert data in call exception
Attempting swap with 0.3% fee...
Quote failed for 0.3% fee: missing revert data in call exception
Attempting swap with 1% fee...
Quote failed for 1% fee: missing revert data in call exception

None of the tokens are swapped, and balances remain the same. Here's the relevant code from my performSwap.js script:
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("Performing swap with account:", signer.address);

  const routerAddress = "0x101F443B4d1b059569D643917553c771E1b9663E";
  const wethAddress = "0xb6c322FA3D8e0A60AfEB17512905eb2229CE7dA5";
  const morAddress = "0xc1664f994Fd3991f98aE944bC16B9aED673eF5fD";
  const poolFees = [500, 3000, 10000]; // 0.05%, 0.3%, 1%

  const routerABI = [
    "function exactInputSingle((address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint24 fee, address recipient, uint256 deadline, uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMinimum, uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96)) external payable returns (uint256 amountOut)",
    "function quoteExactInputSingle(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint24 fee, uint256 amountIn, uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96) external view returns (uint256 amountOut)"
  ];

  const erc20ABI = [
    "function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256)",
    "function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)",
    "function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256)",
    "function decimals() external view returns (uint8)"
  ];

  const router = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerABI, signer);
  const weth = new ethers.Contract(wethAddress, erc20ABI, signer);
  const mor = new ethers.Contract(morAddress, erc20ABI, signer);

  const wethDecimals = await weth.decimals();
  const morDecimals = await mor.decimals();

  const wethBalance = await weth.balanceOf(signer.address);
  const morBalance = await mor.balanceOf(signer.address);
  
  const ethBalance = await signer.getBalance();
  
  const allowance = await mor.allowance(signer.address, routerAddress);

  if (allowance.lt(ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.01", morDecimals))) {
    const approveTx = await mor.approve(routerAddress, ethers.constants.MaxUint256);
    await approveTx.wait();
  }

  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.01", morDecimals);
  const slippageTolerance = 50; 
  const amountOutMinimum = 0; 

  for (const poolFee of poolFees) {
    try {
      const quoteAmountOut = await router.quoteExactInputSingle(morAddress, wethAddress, poolFee, amountIn, 0);
    } catch (error) {
      continue;
    }

    const params = {
      tokenIn: morAddress,
      tokenOut: wethAddress,
      fee: poolFee,
      recipient: signer.address,
      deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20,
      amountIn: amountIn,
      amountOutMinimum: amountOutMinimum,
      sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
    };

    try {
      const tx = await router.exactInputSingle(params, { gasLimit: 500000 });
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
      break; 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Swap failed for ${poolFee / 10000}% fee:`, error.message);
    }
  }

  const wethBalanceAfter = await weth.balanceOf(signer.address);
  const morBalanceAfter = await mor.balanceOf(signer.address);
}
main();


What I've Tried:
Tried various fee tiers (0.05%, 0.3%, 1%)
Checked allowances and balances before and after swap
Used appropriate gas limit for the transaction
Verified the router, token, and pool addresses are correct
Environment:
Testnet: Arbitrum Sepolia
Contracts: Uniswap V3 (Router, Quoter)
Libraries: Hardhat, ethers.js
What could be causing the "Transaction reverted without a reason string" error? How can I debug and resolve this issue?
Tags:

are you sure there is liquidity in the pool? you call continue, if theres no params you still try to execute the swap

You aren't using the correct contract addresses. These are not contracts on Sepolia:
  const routerAddress = "0x101F443B4d1b059569D643917553c771E1b9663E";
  const wethAddress = "0xb6c322FA3D8e0A60AfEB17512905eb2229CE7dA5";
  const morAddress = "0xc1664f994Fd3991f98aE944bC16B9aED673eF5fD";

Also, const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners() will use the local hardhat network. You should instead use a Sepolia provider, for example:
const URL = 'https://1rpc.io/sepolia';
const provider = new ethers.providers.StaticJsonRpcProvider(URL);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY).connect(provider);

where PRIVATE_KEY is your private key with some ETH on testnet.

Hey thanks for responding. Was able to fix my issue. Now am successfully swapping.

Update: Fixed the issue. Was using the wrong abi's for UniversalRouter. Switched to SwapRouter02(Uniswap said there was issues with ARBsepolia universal router on discord.) After switching and updating for correct ABI's I have resolved my issue and now I am successfully swapping.
